# Multi thread safe event in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I'm beginner in Delphi programing.
I use a thread to communicate with my server and I want to pass a Tevent to my thread at creation time and use it to signal a task on this thread from main thread and finally on thread clear the event. This event set in main thread to signal the task on my net thread and finally clear after task completed in the net thread.
I use this line to create thread on run time. All work fine but after adding event to my code rise a problem.

`Net_thread:= TNetThread.Create(user, password, TheCallback, Tevent);`

`TNetThread` is my thread class on other unit and `Net_thread` is my net thread.
`TheCallback` is a procedure for change UI from thread. Declare this type in `TNetThread`.
user, password are login data collected in GUI.
`Tevent` is a handle to my event created in main thread and pass it to `Net_thread`.

Before I add event to my code I only pass 2 string and a procedure to thread and I have no problem. `...Create(user, password, TheCallback);` after add event to my code and pass it as `THandle` to my thread can not use it. Its like a Cardinal variable and when I try to check its state with this code:

`System.SyncObjs.TEvent.WaitFor(FEvent)`

I have an error e2076. FEvent set on constructor `TNetThread.Create` and equal to Tevent received from main thread.

Please give me a simple example?

This is my minimal code:
on main form:

```
procedure TMainform.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  T_event: THandle;
begin
    T_event: := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
    Net_thread:= TNetThread.Create(user, password, TheCallback, T_event);
end;

procedure TMainform.TheCallback(const st,h : String);
begin
    //recive data from net thread
end;
```

on event in main thread
        SetEvent(T_event);

And on other unit

```
type
  TMyCallback = procedure(const st, h : String) of object;

  TNetThread = class(TThread)
    IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient;
  private
    FCallback : TMyCallback;
    FEvent: THandle;
  protected
    procedure execute; override;
    procedure SendLog(st, h: string);
  public
    constructor Create(user_n, psw: string ;aCallback : TMyCallback ; const AEvent: THandle);
  end;

constructor TNetThread.Create(user_n, psw: string ;aCallback: TMyCallback; const AEvent: THandle);
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  FCallback := aCallback;
  FEvent := AEvent;
  user_name := user_n;
  password:= psw;
  FreeOnTerminate := true;
end;

procedure TNetThread.SendLog(st ,h: string);
begin
  if not Assigned(FCallback) then
    Exit;
  Self.Queue(  // Executed later in the main thread
    procedure
    begin
      FCallback(st, h);
    end
  );
end;

procedure TNetThread.Execute;
begin
.
.
    if (System.SyncObjs.TEvent.WaitFor(FEvent) = wrSignaled) then...
.
.
end;
```

Comment: "...my code rise a problem." This is not useful information for us. Please explain the problem you are having in enough detail for us to understand, and with enough relevant code for us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please strip down your code to a minimal complete example. We can't guess what is wrong.

Comment: When using multithreading in delphi, a good starting point is the documentation of the parallel library, What has been very helpful to me is the Omnithread library (free, open source ,very well documented including many samples and very mature) http://www.omnithreadlibrary.com/documentation/#articles

Comment: Your thread is expecting a Win32 event handle, but you are trying to pass that to `TEvent.WaitFor()`, which requires a `SyncObjs.TEvent` object instead. Its single input parameter is a timeout, not an event handle. So, you need to either 1) create an object of the `TEvent` class instead of using the Win32 `CreateEvent()` directly, or 2) use the Win32 `WaitForSingleObject()` function instead of `TEvent.WaitFor()`.

Comment: I agree with @RemyLebeau. And if you want to trigger an event from outside of the thread, it cannot be declared as a local variable in the `FormCreate` method.